# change config file after deploy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

my app reading some values from `app.config`. I don't want to compile app each time I want to change these values and for that I set `Copy always` for config file.

After publishing app I'm getting `Application Files` folder and inside is `appname.exe.config.deploy` file, so I tried to change it's values from

`<add key="dumyname" value="123" />`

to

`<add key="dumyname" value="123123" />`

but when I execute that application it isn't changed (application is writing that value somewhere)

What can I do?

I can't even find where my app is installed

Comment: I think the correct filename should be `appname.exe.config`. Also make sure that your value is in appSettings section not userSettings

Comment: there are only these files: http://prntscr.com/flktag

Comment: It's because those are published files, at install time the files will lose the .deploy extension

Comment: If you want to run your application for test purpose you could use the version in `bin\Debug` of your project folder. or even `bin\Release`

Comment: I don't want for test. I want to install it in my computer and then it will do some things automatically

Comment: But the `appname.exe.config.deploy` file is just a temp file named like that for setup purpose. It shouldn't be edited.

Comment: so what can I do? after installing my app appears in the control panel/programs but can't find where is it installed and it's not in program files as well

Comment: I never tried to make the publish function work. There is a more simple way. You can either use or copy what's in bin/Release (or even bin/Debug) or use a self- extract zip.